# Straightening a curved image in MATLAB

Tags: imagemagick, matlab, image-editing

I registered a video of the experiment that I am carrying on - It is an image of a rotating cylinder. However, when I save the image, the cylinder appears a bit skewed as you can see in the image file I have attached. My question is  can we straighten the cylinder back to its vertical form using MATLAB? If yes, can anyone help me with the code necessary for the operation?

[image]

Comment: The distortion seems to occur because the camera sensor is CMOS, which uses rolling shutter. Perhaps there is a software other than Matlab that fixes it.